# Can XML DTD force different values for two attributes on same element?

Tags: xml, xml-validation, dtd

**Is there a way in XML DTD to force two attributes of the same element to have different values?**

I'm writing an XML application representing a graph, using DTD and not XML Schema.

I declared the element `Link`, having two attributes `host1` and `host2` referring to the attribute `hostName` of the `Host` element with `IDREF`.

I would like to add a kind of constraint (if any) to forbid `host1` and `host2` having the same value (referring to the same host).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, DTD can't express that constraint.  Other options include:

- XSD
- Schematron <sub><sup>[Credit: Thanks, @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen]</sup></sub>
- Application-level validation